# Mismatched type error with functions in a hash map

Tags: function, rust, hashmap

I am trying to create a hash map where the key is a string and the value is a function `fn(&f32,&f32) -> f32`. The error gives me mismatched types and I do not know what I am missing.

```rust
use std::collections{Hashmap}
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
// declared functions
fn fnc1(x:&f32, y: &f32) -> f32 {
    x+y
}
fn fnc2(x:&f32, y: &f32) -> f32 {
    x-y
}

// creating and populating hashmap

lazy_static! {
    static ref OPS: HashMap<&'static str, fn(&f32, &f32) -> f32> = {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("sum", fnc1);
        m.insert("minus", fnc2); // Error occurs on this line with fnc
        m
    };
```

Error below

```
mismatched types
expected fn item `for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a f32, &'b f32) -> _ {fnc1}`
   found fn item `for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a f32, &'b f32) -> _ {fnc2}`
constraint.rs(24, 11): arguments to this function are incorrect
map.rs(1103, 12): associated function defined here
```